# Mongo Repository findById in Java Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-repositories

I have the following `Mongo` repository classs in my `Spring-boot` application, which is called `ExpertRepository.java`:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface ExpertRepository extends MongoRepository<Experts, ObjectId>{
     Experts findBy_id(ObjectId _id);

}
```

And I have implemented this `Service` in my `ExpertsServiceImpl.java` class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpertsServiceImpl implements ExpertsService{

    private final ExpertRepository repository;

    public Experts findExpertById(ObjectId id) {
        Experts searchedExpert = repository.findBy_id(id);
        return searchedExpert;
    } }
```

And I have implemented also the following test class for my `Service` :

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ExpertsServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private  ExpertRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private ExpertsServiceImpl service;


    Experts demoExpert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Steve Jobs", "Enterpreneur",
            Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        service.deleteAll();
        service.createExpert(demoExpert);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        service.deleteAll();
    }


    @Test
    public void testfindExpertById(){
        ObjectId id = new ObjectId(demoExpert.get_id());
        Experts expert =  service.findExpertById(id);
        assertEquals(demoExpert.get_id(), expert.get_id());

    } }
```

Despite that the test fails and when debugging I figured out that my `searchedExpert` object in the `findExpertById` method of the `ExpertsServiceImpl` class is Null as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Does anyone understand why this happens and how I could correct it? I apppreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Are your mongodb connection properties configured properly ? I can't see any problem with your code.

Comment: @SebastianCăşvean yeah mongodb is configured fine